# Find document using array, with or without $in?

Tags: mongoose

I want to find documents in my collection using an array of firstNames. If I do it in plain MongoDB the documentation says i should use $in. But when I use Mongoose, it seems like $in is unnecessary.

#### Setup:

```
const Person = mongoose.model('person', new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type: String, required: true},
  lastName: {type: String, required: true}
})

await Person.create([
  {firstName: 'Pelle', lastName: 'Larsson'},
  {firstName: 'Kalle', lastName: 'Jansson'},
  {firstName: 'Lotta', lastName: 'Nilsson'}
])

const wantedFirstNames = ['Pelle', 'Lotta']
```

#### Find wantedPersons without using $in:

```js
const wantedPersons = await Person.find({firstName: wantedFirstNames})
// Returns two matching documents
```

#### Find wantedPersons using $in:

```js
const wantedPersons = await Person.find({firstName: {$in: wantedFirstNames}})
// Also returns two matching documents
```

Can anyone tell me if it is OK to skip $in or if these two examples does something different. Is this documented somewhere?

### Update

I posted an issue on mongoose github page and received a great answer:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7789
As @HRK44 also says. Mongoose will see that wantedFirstNames is an array and that firstName is a string and therefor use $in anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two solutions are similar.

The piece of documentation that may help you can be found there : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

I think this part is relevant :

> The conditions are cast to their respective SchemaTypes before the
>   command is sent.

Part of the code where this is done might be find there :
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/cast.js#L296

Line 305 :

```
obj[path] = { $in: casted };
```

But I agree that the documentation is not very clear on this matter...

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But I don't think the documentation is very clear about what is happening here. If the conditions are cast to the respective SchemaType, the array would be cast to a string making the condition 
`firstName = "['Pelle','Lotta']"` which should not give me any matches at all...

Comment: @Teodor I added the part of the code where I think this is done. Don't forget that it's a Mongoose Array and the `cast to the respective SchemaType` is just a matter of implementation.

Comment: Ahh! Nice catch finding it in the code @HRK44! So if this is the code in user the result of using $in or not will be the exact same. But maybe it is good to include $in to make my code a bit clearer.  Thanks!
(I added an issue in mongoose github. Hopefully they will make the documentation clearer)